# Searching / filtering with Query Builder, InnerJoin and aliases

Tags: php, laravel, datatable, laravel-blade

Summary of problem or feature request

Hi !

I'm facing to an issue regarding search filtering on a particular QueryBuilder with innerjoin
Summary of problem or feature request

When searching/filtering. Datatables throws this error :
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NOl2t.png)

Code snippet of problem

Here is the select statement with the datatable call :

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xpXlb.png)

Here is the JavaScript columns def
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jMKRf.png)

Comment: Please put your code in the question and don't use images.

Comment: I don't believe you will get any help until the code is in your question rather than links to images with the default link text.

Comment: Image 1 and image 2 are INCONSISTENT - sql query in first not match laravel query in second (e.g. lack of WHERE-LIKE clausule in laravel query). Update question and Put laravel code by copy-paste

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is in this part of the query (third line):

```
where LOWER('ospos_people'.'')
```

You missed the column name.